# Spring MVC returning @ResponseBody content

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, model, return, autowired

I'm new to Java and Spring MVC so apologies in advance if(when) the question is something that should be obvious. I have a simple program that is supposed to use Spring MVC and JPA to store a few messages and then display those as text on a website when the user opens localhost:8080. Some of the code is from a MOOC course that I'm taking and some of it I have modified myself.

I've got 4 files HelloMessage.java, HelloMessageRepository.java, HelloWebWithDatabaseApplication.java and HelloWebWithDatabaseController.java. Contents of the files are pasted below(I omitted the package imports).

HelloMessage.java contains the following:

```
@Entity
public class HelloMessage extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private String content;

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

HelloMessageRepository.java contains the follwing:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface HelloMessageRepository extends JpaRepository<HelloMessage, Long> {

}
```

HelloWebWithDatabaseApplication.java contains this:

```
package sec.helloweb;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloWebWithDatabaseApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWebWithDatabaseApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the last file, HelloWebWithDatabaseController.java, contains this:

```
@Controller
public class HelloWebWithDatabaseController {

    @Autowired
    private HelloMessageRepository helloMessageRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // test data to the application
        HelloMessage msg = new HelloMessage();
        msg.setContent("Hello");
        helloMessageRepository.save(msg);

        HelloMessage msg2 = new HelloMessage();
        msg2.setContent("Web");
        helloMessageRepository.save(msg2);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String list(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("content", helloMessageRepository.findAll());
        return "content";
    }
}
```

When I run the project on Netbeans and check the page it shows the text "content". I would like to print out the messages stored in the helloMessageRepository but I'm not sure on how to do that using the @ResponseBody. If I remove it and create a content.html page it works but how can I just print the messages as text?

Comment: so you want to see "HelloWeb" once you enter localhost:8080? But not through html view?

Comment: I'd like to see both "Hello" and "Web" when I enter localhost:8080 and I'd like it to be plaintext without the need to create a html page beforehand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditionally returning both JSON and (HTML) templates from @RestController in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260292/conditionally-returning-both-json-and-html-templates-from-restcontroller-in-s)